# Access this navigation controller from the code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added a `UITableVIewController` in `Storyboard` and then embedded it in a `Navigation Controller`.

Now, i need to access this navigation controller from the code. How can i do this ?

Normally when  i add a `label` to the application and i can draw an arrow from the storyboard to the `.h` of the `tableviewcontroller.h` file.

But how can i get a reference for the `NavigationController` ?

Comment: Just call `self.navigationController`

Comment: @Wongzigii I don't think that was the question. Illep, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
self.navigationcontroller
```